# Urban Airship crashes at take off. Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

My Code in Applicaion.onCreate. The app crashes at `UAirship.takeoff(this,options);` Please help.

```
public class LiveVideoApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this);

        // Optionally, customize your config at runtime:
        //
        options.inProduction = false;
        options.developmentAppKey = "key.. ";
        options.developmentAppSecret = "secret..";

        UAirship.takeOff(this, options);
        PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);
        Logger.logLevel = Log.VERBOSE;

        //use CustomPushNotificationBuilder to specify a custom layout
        CustomPushNotificationBuilder nb = new CustomPushNotificationBuilder();

        nb.statusBarIconDrawableId = R.drawable.icon_small;//custom status bar icon
//
        nb.layout = R.layout.notification;
        nb.layoutIconDrawableId = R.drawable.icon;//custom layout icon
        nb.layoutIconId = R.id.icon;
        nb.layoutSubjectId = R.id.subject;
        nb.layoutMessageId = R.id.message;

        // customize the sound played when a push is received
        nb.soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+"/" +R.raw.cat);

        PushManager.shared().setNotificationBuilder(nb);
        PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);

    }
}
```

Exception Log:

```
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.LiveVideoApplication: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Application configuration is invalid.
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3275)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:969)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Application configuration is invalid.
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at com.urbanairship.UAirship.takeOff(Unknown Source)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at com.LiveVideoApplication.onCreate(LiveVideoApplication.java:27)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
03-15 00:25:37.106: E/AndroidRuntime(2920):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3272)
```

Comment: Going out on a limb here, but I would say that the `Application configuration is invalid`.

Comment: Need more information. More code, better desription of problem...

Comment: Put more helium into the Airship?

Answer (score 5):

I have also encountered this problem, and I resolved it.  I will suggest you to make sure you have created an app on UrbanAirship with the same package of application which your application have. And also **make sure your key and secret are correct.**

`IllegalArgumentException` is thrown when the **developmentAppKey and developmentAppSecret are wrong.** Or key and secret are correct but your remote Urban Airship test application has a different Applicaion package set.

Answer (score 5):

One thing to note is that if you are using an **airshipconfig.properties** file, and you placed it at the same directory level as the **project.properties** file, the Urban Airship code won't be able to find it, and the call to **AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this)** will return empty string values.

This can cause the exception you are seeing as well.

The solution in this case is to place the **airshipconfig.properties** file in the **assets** directory of your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked every other suggestion, and still get an IllegalArgumentException, this exception is also thrown when the phone doesn't have any associated Google account tied to it.

If this is the case you should be able to login/associate a Google account, and then you have to restart the phone.

I would recommend wrapping the Urban Airship initialisation calls in a try catch to stop it bricking the app in this scenario! If you use error reporting it is wise to log this as a handled exception so you know if and when it is happening.